# Unable to connect to remote server when hitting an API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I am facing a very weird issue:

Case 1: Using ASP.NET Web Development Server: The application hits an API, and everything works fine.

Case 2: I host my application (MVC) on IIS: When the application tries to hit the API, it gets the error:

> "Unable to connect to remote server": {"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 96.17.180.160:80"}

Line of code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(api);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); // This line breaks...
```

Comment: It seems the IIS server does not have access. Have you tried pinging that IP from the server? Have you tried to connect to it via the browser or telnet from the server?

Comment: Yes I have tried to connect to that API through browser it works fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate more like what changes I have to do for proxy settings

Comment: You will have to assign your `request.Proxy` with the settings the required. Make sure it is the problem, as configuring for a proxy is hard and time consuming. What proxy are you running?

Comment: when i tried to ping the api it says cannot find the host.
open cmd -> ping -a url

Comment: You have a network problem then. Do a `tracert` to that host and see where it stops. The problem is there then.

Answer (score 2):

"Unable to connect to remote server" in API, this error is being occurred because that project is not running which project you are calling.
Calling project must be run when you are hitting.
Both project must be  running at same time .

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time this problem is as a result of no response which may be due to a downtime of the remote resource been accessed.

Certain systems face certain downtime issues at certain times. Especially when they have poor infrastructure like shared hosting. Try connecting to another server while engaging this present server and see the responses from both.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have network problems if you cannot ping the remote host. There could be various reasons for that: proxy server, firewall blocking the access, ...

You will have to contact your network administrator to find out more. If he tells you that you need to use a proxy server in order to reach the destination url you could configure this proxy on the request using the [`request.Proxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx) property. You will have to provide the address of the proxy server and any eventual authentication credentials if this proxy requires authentication. Another possibility is to specify global proxy settings in your app/web.config file in the [`<system.net>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx) section.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below settings inside , If proxy/fire wall  is stopping the API call, it will run with below setting.

```
<system.net>
 <defaultProxy>
  <proxy usesystemdefault="false" proxyaddress="Proxyserver:port" bypassonlocal="true"/>
 </defaultProxy> 
</system.net>
```