# When I am trying to view model in Auto-desk Forge am getting Authentication error

Tags: asp.net, autodesk-forge

I have translated the 3D model and trying to view model using Autodesk Forge then am getting Token 500 error

When I ran code in debug mode I got the error message as Autodesk.Forge.Client.ApiException:'Error Calling Authenticate: Unable to connect to the remote server'"

```
 TwoLeggedApi oauthApi = new TwoLeggedApi();
            dynamic bearer = await oauthApi.AuthenticateAsync(
                WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FORGE_CLIENT_ID"],
                WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET"],
                "client_credentials",
                new Scope[] { Scope.BucketCreate, Scope.DataCreate, Scope.DataWrite, Scope.DataRead });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXO05.png)

Comment: It sounds like your asp.net app does not have enough rights to make requests to remote servers. Try looking at something like https://forums.asp.net/t/2070035.aspx?Unable+to+connect+to+the+remote+server.

Comment: Till yesterday it was working as per the requirement.

Comment: Something might have changed (perhaps a Windows update) that affected your application's access to the internet. Note that this issue is already discussed in other Stack Overflow questions, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323284/unable-to-connect-to-remote-server-when-hitting-an-api.

Comment: Can you try isolate the issue by testing if you could obtain an access token using the same credentials with cURL/Postmen etc (see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/authenticate-POST/))? So we could isolate the issue from networking/system environment?