# Access Token giving following Error Message Failed to load resource: The server responded with a status of 500

Tags: autodesk-forge

Here's my problem : I'm currently developing a Forge Autodesk web application, and it requires a token to work. So far I was getting the Token but all of a sudden now i am getting error while accessing token

```
function getAccessToken() {
        var xmlHttp = null;
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        //xmlHttp.open("GET", 'api/forge/token', false /*forge viewer requires SYNC*/);
        xmlHttp.open("GET", 'api/forge/token', true /*forge viewer requires SYNC*/);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        return xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
```

Comment: You mentioned in another stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57069783/when-i-am-trying-to-view-model-in-auto-desk-forge-am-getting-authentication-erro) that your server code stopped working because the Forge SDKs "could not connect to remote server". Has that issue been resolved? If not, this code probably fails because of that - your server side code handling `GET /api/forge/token` requests fails to contact the Forge servers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When I am trying to view model in Auto-desk Forge am getting Authentication error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57069783/when-i-am-trying-to-view-model-in-auto-desk-forge-am-getting-authentication-erro)

Comment: The code/application is working outside of Company network. Is there any port which must be enable to communicate with Autodesk Forge ?

Comment: It is https, so port 443 should be opened